# Django-Rest-Framework: Globally set pagination class in django settings.py

Tags: python, django, rest, pagination, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make a default pagination on all api calls:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#modifying-the-pagination-style

And now I want to make my `CustomPagination` work globally:

```
class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    """
    自定义分页器
    """
    page_size = 10
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000
```

I want the register the class to the `settings.py`:

```
# =========== REST Framework ==============
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'football.views.CustomPagination',
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',),
}
```

Still, it raised an error:

> ImportError: Could not import 'football.views.CustomPagination' for API setting 'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS'. AttributeError: module 'football.views' has no attribute 'CustomPagination'.

How can I work around it?

Comment: I can think of 2 possible problems: 1.) Your `PYTHONPATH` isn't configured correctly so the `football` package isn't on the path. 2.) `football.views.CustomPagination` is accessible from the path but some kind of error happens when django rest framework tries to import/load the `football.views` module. This can happen for example if there is a circular import problem between modules. Start a django shell and try to import this module/class from there. If an error happens then you can be happy because you have a repro. No error still doesn't mean that import would work from a different context.

Comment: can you post the path of where your CustomPagination is? It sounds like you're having path issues.

Comment: @jarussi `[project_dir]/football/views.py`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and finally I fingered out it was because the module `views.py` was not correctly loaded because I didn't create the rest api folder by `manage.py startapp` and there is no item for it in `INSTALLED_APPS` of project's `setting.py` file.
I moved the `CustomPagination` paging class to `views.py` of my first app which was created by `manage.py startapp` then it worked.

To debug, you can add following line to [rest_framework/settings.py source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/settings.py#L179) like this:

```
module = import_module(module_path)  # Original code
if (setting_name == "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS"):  # Added code
    print(dir(module))  # Added code
return getattr(module, class_name)   # Original code
```

If `AttributeError` raised, it should be like: (only builtin attributes in the list)

```
# ./manage.py runserver 0:8000
Performing system checks...

['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
Unhandled exception in thread started by .wrapper at 0x7fd60a265510>
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

If it works, `CustomPagination` should be listed in the list:

```
# ./manage.py runserver 0:8000
Performing system checks...

['some-other-classes', 'PageNumberPagination', 'CustomPagination', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'models', 'random', 'reverse', 'settings']
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```